# Require a single module from a bundled library (i.e. jquery-ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, requirejs, jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

I am creating an application with durandal, which means I'm using `requirejs`.
I decided to use the mighty `knockout-sortable` plugin. As it turns out, it uses `jquery-ui` features internally, which is nice. I also have defined the whole `jquery-ui` package in my app, so in my `requirejs` configuration it figures as

```
"jqueryui": "../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom",
```

What is more, the plugins author is using AMD loading to get `jquery.ui.sortable`, and here's the problem. The `jquery-ui` doesn't seem to define itself with `requirejs`, neither the whole package nor single modules.

Do I have to import any module from `jquery-ui` separately and for each define path in `requirejs` config so it is explicitly visible or is there a way to tell `requirejs` that there's already this `jquery.ui.sortable` module around inside `jquery-ui` that the plugin is asking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to setup a simple alias either using a `path` requirejs config

```
paths: {
  'jquery.ui.sortable': 'jquery-ui'
}
```

Or if that doesn't work, you could use the `map` config

```
map: {
  '*': {
    'jquery.ui.sortable': 'jquery-ui'
  }
}
```

Or when using `map`, you could even only setup alias for that one plugin

```
map: {
  'THE-JQUERY-UI-PLUGIN-ID': {
    'jquery.ui.sortable': 'jquery-ui'
  }
}
```

That last one makes it so that whevener the plugin in question makes a `require("jquery.ui.sortable")` call it actually pulls in `jquery-ui` module which you know has the sortable functionality built in already.

There also exists a `jquery-ui-amd` project which I quite like using. That project converts all `jquery-ui` modules into individual AMD modules https://github.com/jrburke/jqueryui-amd. You could use that for an easier and more modular integration into your project. However, even then you would need some aliasing as your plugin requires `jquery.ui.sortable`, but in `jquery-ui-amd` the id would be `jquery-ui/sortable`.

Comment: Seems like a simple and painless solution, thank you. I'll try and implement it this way at work tomorrow and give you feedback here. Also thank you for bringing up this `jquery-ui` modular version.